# Vertical arrangement with asterisk

Tags: java

How to do this. vertical arrangement of the asterisk using java.. plz help me. based on the values on arrays. ex. {3,4,2,5}  how to display the output in the example.

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9BgE.png)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: i tried this one. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148746-java-simple-histogram/   the concept is right, but i am in trouble on how to display vertical output.

Answer (score 1):

For each row, you print a new line.

So the first row gets a star for in the column that has a value greater than 4.
The next row gets a star for each column that has a value greater than 3

and so on. Of course the columns that do not get a star must in a row must get a blank.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] a = new int[] {3,4,2,5};
int[] tmp = a.clone();

Arrays.sort(tmp);
int max = tmp[tmp.length-1];

for (int i = 0; i < max+1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {        
        if (i == max) {
            System.out.print(a[j]);
        } else {        
            if (i < max - a[j])
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
                System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```