# Histogram based on int array and negative values

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

I've a question to you.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975968/vertical-arrangement-with-asterisk#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975968/vertical-arrangement-with-asterisk#_=_)

The code which you shared this post is very good. I've an exam tomorrow. May you tell me the solution.
I edited int array in this program. 
It's {-1, 2, 5, 3} but program is not printing (-1) value in which int array. 
I want to   When the loop read this minus value, it cross new line and print "*" and print the minus value to its underline.

Can you tell me how can i do that in Java?
Thank you.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESsVE.jpg

Comment: If you have an exam tomorrow, today is a bit to late to start at the beginning. Basically, you just copied some code, don't understand why it doesn't do what you want it to do, and want us to fix it, right?

Comment: you even fail to figure out how to post a question on SO. How much time have you spent studying Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    int[] a = new int[] {-1,3,-4,2,5};
    int[] tmp = a.clone();

    Arrays.sort(tmp);
    int max = tmp[tmp.length-1];
    int low = tmp[0];
    int last =max;
    if(low<0) {
        last=max-low;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < last+1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {        
            if (i == last ) {
                System.out.print(a[j]);
            } else if(i<max){        
                if (i < max - a[j])
                    System.out.print(" ");
                else
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            else {
                if (i < max - a[j] )
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.  I never thought it would be so easy. Thanks again.